# DOS interrupt problem with int 21h 0ah

Tags: assembly, dos

I have this assembly code that reads a string of 120 bytes. If I try to fill the buffer by pressing a key until it stops writing, the enter key doesn't work. I counted the characters and I found that I have written 121 characters.

Is this normal? Is there a way to avoid it? Another interruption perhaps?

The code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.386
.data 
    MSG DB "Please give me the string (max 120 chars): ", 10, 13, "$"
    Sentence1 DB 121,?,121 dup(0)
.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,A
    int 21h

    xor ax,ax        
    mov dx, offset Sentence1
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h
    xor bx,bx
    mov bl, Sentence1[1]
    mov Sentence1[bx+2], '$' 

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
end start
```

An example (imagine that is a 11 bytes buffer and not 121 bytes, for brevity):

```
Please give me the string (max 10 chars):
AAAAAAAAAAA
\_________/
     |
    11 As
```

If I press Enter at this point it doesn't work, but if I delete an A and press Enter, then it works.

I use Tasm and Tlink for compiling.

Regards.

[Edit] A typo.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this normal?

Yes.

> Is there a way to avoid it?

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> to exit buffered-input mode (this results in an `INT 23h`).

> Another interruption perhaps?

There are several DOS interrupt services that you could use to read input, but `INT 21h`/`AH=01h` is probably the next best option.

Comment: And if you want to see the actual code behind `INT 21h`/`AH=0Ah`, see https://www.google.com/webhp?q=%22cpmio.asm%22

Comment: see http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/why-int-21h-ah-0ah-doesnt-work-in-emu86 for the explanation - the enter key requires its own buffer slot.  If you fill the buffer completely, then you can't press enter.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Now I have it clear. I tried with Emu8086 and it worked the another way around. Seems that is because of how dosbox emulates.